# Insert mode remap to insert an underscore

Tags: key-bindings

I am starting to have issues with my pinky finger. I tend to write variables and functions using underscores as in `my_variable`. I would like to find a way to avoid having to press "shift + -" to get the underscore. One way I thought of is by having vim transform `--` to `_` automatically as I type. How can I do that? Other alternatives to writing `_` are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about your pinky. :)

You could try one of...

```
:inoremap -- _
```

...or...

```
:iabbrev -- _
```

The difference has to do with when the substituted character appears. With mappings it's immediately. With abbreviations it's after you type a *non-keyword* character (e.g. <kbd>Space</kbd>).

Of course, if your primary use case is, as you suggested, *snake_case* variable names...and so the underscore is always followed by a *keyword* character...then the first one is the only practical choice! The alternative may be of interest to other folks, though.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complicated solution that mirrors what I do for SHOUTY CAPS.

For upper case, I type in lower case and then use something like `gUiw` to change the case.

For `-` to `_`, I would use tpope's [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) to type `my-variable` and then use `cr_` (which only needs one `_` typed) or `crs` (which needs none).